# Develop a Maven web-app-archetyp project with Eclipse Juno m2e

Tags: maven, web-applications, m2eclipse, eclipse-juno

I begin a projet with Maven Spring under Eclipse Juno.
I create the project with m2eclipse wtp.
The hierarchy looks like this.

```
> src/
>     main/
>         java/
>             com/
>                 example/
>                     web/
>                         HomeController.java
>         resources/
>              Spring
>         webapp/
>             img/
>             css/
```

My project is working, but i'don't know if i put the files in a "correct way".
I mean , i created directory for css and img. Do i have to create them under WEB-INF, or just under Webapp,or in package /src/main/ressources?
Is it correct with the Maven spirit ?
I dont understand why /src/main/ressources looks like a package in eclipse juno whereas it should contain only bean file? (or maybe css, javascript..i'm asking the question!?).

How is the best way to organise the files with this configuration? What is the traditional way to develop in Eclipse Juno a maven-archetype-webapp with m2eclipse ?

One last question , i don't understand why appears Deployed Ressources and Java Resources speudo repertory in Eclipse ?

Humm I'm not very clear :/

But if someone have already experience same configuration (Eclipse Juno m2e, Maven-archetype-webapp, Spring ) How have you done your architecture?

Thanks a lot for sharing your experience !

Comment: That looks fine to me. Everything that should be publicly accessible goes in `src/main/webapp`, such as html, img, css, etc. Everything in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` is hidden from the public.

Comment: Ok cool. And for javascript? I created a javascript directory under webapp but Eclipse juno handle it oddly . I put Jquery. An error occur in project Explorer Directory.why ?

Comment: What do you mean by oddly? What do you mean by error? Show logs and/or screenshots please.

Comment: I post here screenshots. Thanks for you help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988162/eclipse-juno-m2ecliipse-directory-structure-explanation