# Eclipse Juno m2ecliipse : directory structure explanation

Tags: maven, directory, package, m2eclipse, eclipse-juno

I'm working under Eclipse Juno on a maven-archetype-webapp project done with m2eclipse.

I don't understand directory structure. Anyone could explain how it's working?

Thanks

[image]

What i src/main/ressources for ? When you create package, it's not showed as package but only directory.
I create a /src/main/java package and it's where i put my classes. The package structure hierarchy is ok.

What is librairies ressources? Is it where you put javascript jquery? but when i put jquery plugin it does a lot of effor in the project manager. And i want my javascript under /webapp/javascript... What is ECMAScript Library ? What to do with that, what is for?

Same question about Deployed Ressources and target and Jax-WS Web Services ?

Ok target must be the directory when you build the project maven, but i can't see the war file. When you run build how to configure it in eclipse to generate the build? What is the command ?

Thanks , i know it's a lot of questions but i'm beginner !

Have a great day :)

I just add the example when you put jquery in webapp
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[All of this is explained here.](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

- **src/main/java** This is where your source code goes
- **src/main/resources** This is where you put your resources like your xml files.  Things that aren't java classes but need to be in your classpath.  If you put them under /java, they won't be copied into your classpath so you have to put them here.
- **src/main/webapp** This is for webapps.  Everything you put in here will be copied over to your war file, directly.

Comment: Ok thanks ! I put my xml files under webapp/WEV-INF(applicationContext.xml, faces-config.xml,web.xml). Do i have to put them under src/main/ressources ? I don't the goal of this directory. What is the good way ? Do this have an impact on the build ? And how i do the build with maven under eclipse and where the war is created?( under target ? I don't retrieve it) . And i'm still in trouble with the javascript jquery plugin , any idea?

Comment: u r on rt path. Put your xml in webapp/web-inf/. The resources directory serves to be the location where you want your non-class files to be on the claspath. If you suppose create any project in eclipse & want to run it inside eclipse itself then this folder you can use for putting your non-classpath resources. Also, the contents from this folder are copied to your build file (final war/jar file).To make a war file for webapp with m2e, use goal "mvn install".ur war will be built and will be available from target directory (need refresh on project sometimes if u dont see it in one go :-).

Comment: You are using the "Package" view which shows many virtual categories and can be confusing. Try the "Navigator" view which shows the actual physical locations of files. Those main/java main/resources, main/webapp folders are standard maven locations. What goes where is a maven question, not an eclipse question. Your question indicates you may be mixing up eclipse/maven issues. As for how to build with maven under eclipse, create a new Maven "run configuration" (Run -> Run configurations...) and run it.  Take a look at eclipse and maven documentation or tutorials.

Comment: I meant "Project Explorer" view not "Package" view.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. Ok for running maven build, I did it ,:-) In the project explorer i have both the two views package view is useful for java classes.At the bottom, i have the actual physicals locations of files.I still don't understand src/main/ressources, hummm if i I put my xml files under webapp/WEV-INF(Context.xml,web.xml), what kind of files, i put there ? /. The resources directory serves to be the location where you want your non-class files to be on the classpath ...ok ...an example could be? what the difference with WEB-INF, except the classpath stuff ?